# Is it possible to monitor jboss if it happens to run out of memory?

Tags: java, jboss, monitoring, out-of-memory

Sometimes when I redeploy war too many times, jboss gives ***java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space*** error, is it possible to monitor jboss with other Java program that is not run inside jboss, to make sure it has not run ot of memory and if it is, then automatically restart jboss?

Comment: interresting, same behaviour as with tomcat... maybe jboss has tomcat behind? Or this is something with Java?

Comment: It's because of jboss classloader, i don't know if tomcat has smae "feature" 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307080/jboss-4-0-2-deploying-same-war-multiple-times-causes-jboss-to-crash-because-of-pe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that you can monitor the memory consumption via JMX and the MemoryMXBean. You can do this interactively via [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), or code up a simple monitor to do this automatically.

[Here's some details](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=91821553) on how to do this in-process, but you can do this remotely as well. See the JMX docs for more info.

*Alternatively*, you can run a process under the [JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp), and get it to shutdown/restart a process depending on messages coming out from stdout/err. That may be a simple way to perform your restart automatically. However, I'd prefer using the JMX solution in the long term so you can get advance warning of issues (and perhaps tie them to their underlying cause).

Comment: By the time OutOfMemoryExceptions start flying, won't it be non-responsive to remote JMX calls? You won't get nice notifications so much as your JMX client would start getting connection timeout exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [HypericHQ](http://www.hyperic.com/). It's a very good standalone application that can monitor your JBoss instances, alert you when the permgen or heap gets low, and can even trigger a restart if required. It's a complex beast, but worth the investment.